# What is the meaning of Hawkeye words: "diliation and curettage"?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, m.a.s.h

In [M.A.S.H](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066026/), Hawkeye Pierce says these words in Surgical Tent When he heard moaning in the Radio:

> Hawkeye Pierce: Looks like Dr. Frank Burns is doing a bit of
>   **dilatation and curettage**.

I googled this words but it is way different from **moaning** meaning.

Comment: What does "moaning" meaning mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Hawkeye was making a joke/double entendre by insinuating that Frank Burns is performing a legitimate medical procedure "Dilation and curettage", instead of just fooling around with Margaret Houlihan.

I believe this is also the scene where Major Houlihan earns the moniker "Hot Lips"?

Answer (score 2):

A dilation and cutterage is a procedure done by gynecologist to obtain samples from a female's uterus. Hawkeye in the film MASH said this when hearing along with the entire camp, Majors Burns and O'Houlihan moaning during sexual intercourse after Radar O'Reilly placed the camp's intercom mic under O'Houlihan's cot. I learned what a "D&C" was back in 1997 when my then girlfriend who was a Navy corpsman(nurse) explained it to me.